# Similar Oracle to_date and to_timestamp in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I Have these two conversion function in my Oracle Insert SQL.

```
Insert Into MyTable(id,date1,timeStamp1) 
             values(1,To_date('22-JUN-17', 'DD-MON-RR'),
                    To_timestamp('22-JUN-17 11.53.25 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'));
```

I would like to convert this instruction to run on Cassandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra 2.2 and above supports `toTimeStamp(timeuuid)` and `toDate(timeuuid)` functions

Example from Doc:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_times (a int, b timestamp, c timeuuid, d bigint, PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c,d));
INSERT INTO sample_times (a,b,c,d) VALUES (1, toUnixTimestamp(now()), 50554d6e-29bb-11e5-b345-feff819cdc9f, toTimestamp(now()));
```

[TimeUUID functions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html)

Comment: Tks @undefined_variable.

Comment: @AndersonRossi glad i could help